# Nativescript camera take multiple pictures before returning to the app

Tags: nativescript

I have a NS 4.1.3 application using TS where I use the [nativescript-camera plugin](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera) to allow the user to take photos which are saved to the device's photos library.

Everything works great, however, after each photo the camera closes and the user is back at the app and if they want to take another picture they have to go through the same process.

Is there a way to open the camera, take multiple pictures and only when done return back to the app?  I could not find anything on the plugin's github page.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting `saveToGallery` to `true`? Last time i checked, i saved all the photos taken to the gallery

Comment: I did not set this explicitly, I thought it was the default because the photos are saved to the gallery.  I will try that and will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [navivescript-camera-plus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus)

They have done a great job exposing the Camera and Library functionality via the plugin's api.

Answer (score 2):

you can't take multiple photos in one session using native camera api due to platform limitation. what you can do is capture camera session using AVCaptureSession for ios and CameraCaptureSession camera2 api for android and then show it to user. after that on some button click capture photo.

here is some plugins which might help you:

https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-cameraApp-poc

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-camera-preview